# ruby how to close a mechanize connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize, open-uri

I have the problem with Too many connection on mechanize and I wounder how I close a connection since I want to build a scraper with proxy.

I did find the

```
agent.shutdown
```

but for somereason I cant get that to work. any help ?

```
10.times {

    minion = Mechanize.new { |mech|
        mech.open_timeout   = 15
        mech.read_timeout   = 15

    }

    minion.set_proxy '212.82.126.32', 80


    page = minion.get("http://www.whatsmyip.org/")
    proxy_ip_adress = page.parser.css('#ip').text
    puts proxy_ip_adress
    minion.shutdown

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll want to use a Mechanize#start block:

```
10.times do
  Mechanize.start do |minion|
    minion.open_timeout   = 15
    minion.read_timeout   = 15

    minion.set_proxy '212.82.126.32', 80

    page = minion.get("http://www.whatsmyip.org/")
    proxy_ip_adress = page.parser.css('#ip').text
    puts proxy_ip_adress
  end
  # minion definitely doesn't exist anymore
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works!! I also added begin, rescue to it so that it wont break if the proxy is dead it moves along. Thank you so much

Comment: by any chance you maybe have a tip on how to make it loop until it finds a proxy that works and can get the site ? I am using this code for random proxies proxies = @proxies.order("RANDOM()").first

Have tried begin rescue, but it will only retry with the same proxy. mind = blank here